# (CAPL) I want to assign same values in the specific array. how can I use "memcpy"?

Tags: capl

I am new using CAPL. I want to make int array with same value(3).
Below is okay.. (No error)
However, As you could see this, this is way too complicated and hard to change the array value.

```
int a[102] =  
      {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
       3, 3};
```

I thought this could work but it was not.

```
int b = 2;
int a[102] = memcpy(a, b, elCount(a));
```

How can I assign `int` array with same value?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `memcpy` in CAPL similar to `memcpy` in C. But `memcpy` does not do, what you seem to expect.

`memcpy` copies a number of bytes from a certain memory area to your destination. So in order to be able to copy the list of `3`s as in your example, you would need to a have a memory area containing 102 `3`s. Which puts you back to start.

Maybe you mean `memset`, which does not exist in CAPL.

---

Why not use a simple for-loop?

```
int a[102];
for(int i=0; i<elcount(a); i++) {
  a[i] = 3;
}
```

There is only a single place to change the value.
If you want you can even wrap that in a CAPL function and make `a` and the value a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
However, I could not use "for loop" in the variables section. How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to initialize your variable in the code, e.g. in `on start` or similar. Also memset could not be used in the variables section.

Comment: Thank you. Here is what I did in the "on start" section. 
Your additional comment was really helpful. 

                       for (i=0; i<elcount(a); i++) { a[i] = 1; }